# template multiplication VBA for excel does not work with Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba, templates, multiplication

I have a code i used in Excel 2010 VBA to multiply identified template - worksheets to target worksheets using a list in the "Instructions" worksheet. It worked fine with my Excel 2010. But when i try to run it from Excel 2013, i get an error of incompatible code... Below is my code... can any one help to identify which part of code is not supported in later Excel versions?

```
Option Explicit
Sub SheetsFromTemplate()
On Error GoTo errorhandler
Dim resp As Boolean
Dim wsMASTER As Worksheet, wsTEMP1 As Worksheet
Dim wasVISIBLE1 As Boolean
Dim shNAMES As Range, Nm As Range
Dim NmSTR, trgt As String
With ThisWorkbook                                               'keep focus in this workbook
    Set wsTEMP1 = Worksheets(Range("A1").Value)          'sheet to be copied
    wasVISIBLE1 = (wsTEMP1.Visible = xlSheetVisible)             'check if it's hidden or not
    If Not wasVISIBLE1 Then wsTEMP1.Visible = xlSheetVisible     'make it visible
    Set wsMASTER = Worksheets("Instructions")                           'sheet with names
    trgt = wsMASTER.Range("B1").Value                                                            'range to fill in target
    If trgt = "" Then
        resp = MsgBox("No value specified in target cell range, do you want to continue without a value input ?", vbYesNo, "SK-tools")
        If resp = False Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        trgt = "A1048576"
    End If
    Set shNAMES = wsMASTER.Range("A3:A" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlConstants)     'or xlFormulas
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False                          'speed up macro
    For Each Nm In shNAMES                                      'check one name at a time
        NmSTR = FixStringForSheetName(CStr(Nm.Text))            'use UDF to create a legal sheetname
        If Not Evaluate("ISREF('" & NmSTR & "'!A1)") Then       'if sheet does not exist...
            wsTEMP1.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)        '...create it from template
            ActiveSheet.Name = NmSTR                  '...rename it
            ActiveSheet.Range(trgt).Value = NmSTR              '...Paste the sheet name
        End If
    Next Nm
    wsMASTER.Activate                                           'return to the master sheet
    If Not wasVISIBLE1 Then wsTEMP1.Visible = xlSheetHidden      'hide the template if necessary
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True                           'update screen one time at the end
End With
resp = MsgBox("Completed multiplication of templates", vbInformation, "SK-Tools")
Exit Sub
errorhandler:
    resp = MsgBox("Contact the developer for troubleshooting code error" & Error, vbCritical, "SK-Tools")
    If Not wasVISIBLE1 Then wsTEMP1.Visible = xlSheetHidden      'hide the template if necessary
End Sub

Function FixStringForSheetName(shSTR As String) As String
'replace each forbidden character with something acceptable
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, ":", "")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "?", "")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "*", "")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "/", "-")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "\", "-")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "[", "(")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "]", ")")
'sheet names can only be 31 characters
    FixStringForSheetName = Trim(Left(shSTR, 31))
End Function
```

Comment: Did you try to step through the lines to check which line throws the error?

Comment: Thanks Zac for your comment, yes i tried to step through the code. following line have issues :

Comment: errorhandler: resp = MsgBox("Contact the developer for troubleshooting code error" & Error, vbCritical, "SK-Tools")

Comment: If Not Evaluate("ISREF('" & NmSTR & "'!A1)") Then

Comment: FixStringForSheetName = Trim(Left(shSTR, 31))